# Parsing an IP address (Bit manipulation)

Tags: java, algorithm, bitwise

Given a string representing of an IP address, such as "127.43.23.59", return a 32 bit integer representation of this string. The 32 bit integer is separated into four bytes, where each byte is one of the numbers in the string, separated by dots. If you  & 0xFF with the returned integer, it should return 59. If you & 0xFF00 with the returned integer, it should return 23, etc.

```
public class IP{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IP address = new IP();
        int x = address.IPAddress("127.43.29.56");
    }
    public int IPAddress(String str)
    {
        int byte1 = 0;
        int numbers[] = new int[4];
        int index = 0;
        int finalByte = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) != '.')
                byte1 = 10*byte1 + (str.charAt(i) - 48);
            else
            {
                numbers[index++] = byte1;
                byte1 = 0;
            }
        }
        numbers[index] = byte1;
        return finalByte = (numbers[0]<<24) | (numbers[1]<<16)|
                    (numbers[2]<<8) | (numbers[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You surely mean that *"If you & 0xFF00 with the returned integer, it should return 5888"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First impressions

Some basic issues that immediately jump in the eye:

- A method that doesn't need data in member fields can be static. The `IPAddress` method looks like a good candidate for a static utility method in an `IPAddressUtils` class.
- The Java convention is `camelCase` for method names (violated by `IPAddress`)
- Poor naming: the `IPAddress` method takes a dotted decimal notation and returns a 32-bit integer representation. The name "IPAddress" does very little to describe that
- `finalByte` is unused, unnecessary
- Unusual declaration: instead of `int numbers[]`, the convention is `int[] numbers`
- Unusual formatting

#### Simplification

You don't need an `int[]` to calculate the value. You need just one value, and shift it to the left by 8 bits for each parsed byte value.

Instead of the number 48 for `'0'`, you can just use `'0'` to make the meaning obvious.

#### Suggested implementation

Applying the above suggestions, here's a utility class:

```
public class IPAddressUtils {

    public static int toInt(String dottedDecimal) {
        int byte1 = 0;
        int value = 0;
        for (char c : dottedDecimal.toCharArray()) {
            if (c != '.') {
                byte1 = 10 * byte1 + (c - '0');
            } else {
                value <<= 8;
                value += byte1;
                byte1 = 0;
            }
        }
        value <<= 8;
        value += byte1;
        return value;
    }
}
```